# Handle permissions with groups in linux

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, user-permissions, usergroups

I can't understand how exactly this works in Linux.

For example, I want only users in some group have access to execute some file (I hope this is possible without `visudo`).

I create a system user and system group like:

```
 useradd -K UID_MIN=100 -K UID_MAX=499 -K GID_MIN=100 -K GID_MAX=499 -p \* -s /sbin/nologin -c "testusr daemon,,,"  -d "/var/testusr" testusr
```

I add my current user `user` to the group `testusr` (may be not cross platform):

```
 adduser user testusr
```

I create some test shell file and set permissions:

```
 touch test.sh
 chmod ug+x test.sh
 sudo chown testusr:testusr test.sh
```

But I still can't start test.sh as `user`:

```
 ./test.sh
 -> Error
```

Now I look for some system groups like `cdrom` to check how they work. My `user` is in `cdrom` group and can use the cd rom on my computer:

```
$ ls -al /dev/cdrom
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 апр.  17 12:55 /dev/cdrom -> sr0
$ ls -al /dev/sr0
brw-rw----+ 1 root cdrom 11, 0 апр.  17 12:55 /dev/sr0
```

**Addition:**

`./test.sh` command starts to work as I want after system reboot. Strange...

I'm on Ubuntu Studio 15.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The group changes are reflected only upon re-login.